# Appium Desktop - Could not find 'adb'

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

I am trying to use the inspector in the Appium Desktop for Mac.  After I add my desired capabilities, I get the following error:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb","/$HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator/adb","/$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools/adb","/$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '$HOME/Android/Sdk'?
```

I am normally using `Zsh`, and I have this added to my `.zshrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

When I type `abd --version` in zshell I see that I have version 1.0.41 installed, so it's working my terminal.  My first thought was that Appium is using bash, so I added those lines to `~/.bash_profile` (and `source`d it), then restarted Appium and tried to start an inspector session, but I got the same error.  I then noticed that I can Edit Configurations, which in version 1.17.1 means setting the JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME environment variables.  I tried adding these configurations to Appium Desktop:

```
ANDROID_HOME:  $HOME/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME:     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I then restarted Appium, but I got the same error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration to Appium Desktop:

```
ANDROID_HOME:  /Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME:     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Change `$HOME`